# Enable mouse wheel scrolling in combobox/listbox

Tags: excel, excel-2007, mousewheel, userform, vba

I am building a userform in Excel 2007 using VBA and would like to know how to enable mouse wheel scrolling of comboboxes and listboxes.

Do I need a more recent version of Office to get this feature or is it something that can be coded for?

Comment: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/447609-visual-basic-applications-help-scroll-wheel-mouse-listbox.html

Comment: Then http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-178071.html

Comment: Alternative solution: [VBA UserForm MouseScroll](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-UserForm-MouseScroll)

Answer (score 1):

if using 32-bit Windows then the solutions by **PETER THORNTON** using WIN32 API calls on the below page will help:

[MSDN Forums - Visual Basic For Applications: Mouse scroll in UserForm ListBox in Excel 2010](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/7d584120-a929-4e7c-9ec2-9998ac639bea/)

The OP on that page was using Excel 2010 but as it's API calls doing the work, so long as you are using 32-bit Windows then that should work for you too.

Philip

Comment: Thank you! But I am using a 64-bit version of Windows 7, does this mean I am out of luck?

Comment: ah, well, it certainly means the answer I gave won't be much help :) Take a look at these: [Stack Overflow: how-should-i-make-my-vba-code-compatible-with-64-bit-windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506912/how-should-i-make-my-vba-code-compatible-with-64-bit-windows) and [Stack OverFlow: What are the differences between VBA 6 and VBA7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072356/what-are-the-differences-between-vba-6-0-and-vba-7-0)

Comment: what version of Office are you using (32-bit or 64-bit)?

Comment: more reading for you: [MSDN: Compatibility Between the 32-bit and 64-bit Versions of Office 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831.aspx#odc_office2010_Compatibility32bit64bit_IntroducingVBA7CodeBase)

Comment: My version of Office 2007 is 32-bit.

Comment: ok, but for API calls it is the version of Windows here that is critical.