# Drop-Down List Detached From ComboBox - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

The drop down list of a ActiveX ComboBox detaches whenever I scroll down the page. How 
can I fix it so it won't move?

Here's the VBA code designated for the comboBox.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "DropDownList"
Me.ComboBox1.DropDown

End Sub
```

Comment: As a note this behavior does exist as early as Excel 2003, so I suggest a tag modification.

Comment: I want to wait for other responses.

Answer (score 1):

If you switch out your ComboBox to the one from the Forms toolbar, then it collapses the list as soon as you start scrolling. I think the "detaching" of the dropdown is the default behavior and I don't think you can influence that programmatically ([as in here, too](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/485953-scrolling-activex-combobox.html)).

See this post on the different options for the comboboxes:

[Run Macro When ComboBox is Clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007492/run-macro-when-combobox-is-clicked/37010106#37010106)

Another option is to disable the mouse scroll, as in this post:

[VBA Excel Combobox: drop-down list scrolling issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594075/vba-excel-combobox-drop-down-list-scrolling-issue/21509044#21509044)