# I'm trying to convert this PtrSafe to 64 bit and I've added the Win64 and LongPtr but it still is highlighted in red. Any suggestions?

Tags: vba

I'm trying to convert this PtrSafe to 64 bit and I've added the Win64 and LongPtr but it still is highlighted in red.  Any suggestions?

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public lngRefNum As LongPtr
Public blnSetupCK As Boolean

#If Win64 Then

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
            Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
           (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
            ByVal lpOperation As String, _
            ByVal lpFile As String, _
            ByVal lpParameters As String, _
            ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
            ByVal nShowCmd As LongPtr) As Long
            
#Else
        Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
            Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
           (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
            ByVal lpOperation As String, _
            ByVal lpFile As String, _
            ByVal lpParameters As String, _
            ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
            ByVal nShowCmd As LongPtr) As Long
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506912/how-should-i-make-my-vba-code-compatible-with-64-bit-windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I make my VBA code compatible with 64-bit Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506912/how-should-i-make-my-vba-code-compatible-with-64-bit-windows)