Why does my Access vba open the PDF but then close it after a few seconds?
On button click, my code uses Application.FollowHyperlink to open a PDF that lives on a remote server. The folder containing that file has been shared by giving full control to everyone. The file opens up with Adobe Acrobat, which is weird since the default program to open a PDF on the local server is set to Chrome. The file then closes after about 4 seconds, not sure why. I can navigate to the folder where the file lives on the local server and open it with Chrome just fine. I can also RDP into the remote server and open the file there using Edge by default with no issues. The remote server does not have Adobe Acrobat installed.
Private Sub btnOpenCert_Click()
   
   Dim WO As String
   Dim CoCFolder As String
   Dim CustPO As String
   Dim FilePath As String

   WO = FieldOnForm

   '...run a stored procedure using an ADODB connection, then interpret results...
   
   CoCFolder = GetCoCFolder()
   CustPO = GetPropertyFromWO(WO, 1)
   FilePath = CoCFolder & CustPO & "_" & WO & ".pdf"
   Application.FollowHyperlink FilePath
   
ExitLabel:
   Exit Sub
   
ErrLabel:
   ErrHandler Err.Number, Err.Description
   Resume ExitLabel

End Sub


So FilePath is a shared network path like \\remoteservername\path\file.pdf ?   You mention "local server" - are all users logged in to this server via RDP, and is that where they're running Access?

@TimWilliams yes, the full filepath is \\sqldev1\ATS Shared Files\CertificateOfConformance\123074_652031000.pdf. I am the only user for now. I have a physical PC that RDPs into a VM. I have my Access program in that VM that runs the code in my question when I click a button.

I'm not why the PDF auto-closes in that situation but from a quick Google this has been noted before.  Eg see https://www.office-forums.com/threads/pdf-opens-then-closes.609238/ (that post has a workaround)

Work-around adapted from the link I posted above:
Option Explicit

Private Const SW_SHOW = 5 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow

Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
        (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _
        ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long


Sub tester()
    Dim pdf As String
    pdf = "\\serverHere\path1\path2\someDocument.pdf"
    
    Debug.Print gbOpenFile(pdf)
End Sub


Public Function gbOpenFile(rsPath As String) As Boolean
    If ShellExecute(0, "open", rsPath & vbNullChar, vbNullString, _
                     vbNullString, SW_SHOW) > 32 Then
        gbOpenFile = True
    End If
End Function

Note this is for 32-bit: you will need to make any appropriate changes if you have 64-bit Access.

I added PtrSafe after Private Declare and it crashed Access after I saved and went back to Form View on my form. After restarting, it seems to be working fine, but the crash worries me. I can't have this crashing in production. Do you know if there is more to do in updating this code to 64-bit Access?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506912/how-should-i-make-my-vba-code-compatible-with-64-bit-windows

We've seen similar issues, but ShellExecute will bring you in control.
This is our complete production code:
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' API declarations for OpenDocumentFile.
' Documentation:
'   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea
'
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal lpOperation As String, _
    ByVal lpFile As String, _
    ByVal lpParameters As String, _
    ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
    ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
    As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDesktopWindow Lib "user32" () _
    As Long
    
' Enum for ShowWindow constants (selection).
' Documentation:
'   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow
'
Public Enum SwShowCommand
    swShowNormal = 1
    swShowMinimized = 2
    swShowMaximized = 3
End Enum
   
' Open a document file using its default viewer application.
' Optionally, the document can be opened minimised or maximised.
'
' Returns True if success, False if not.
' Will not raise an error if the path or file is not found.
'
' 2022-03-12. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function OpenDocumentFile( _
    ByVal File As String, _
    Optional ByVal ShowCommand As SwShowCommand = swShowNormal) _
    As Boolean

    Const OperationOpen     As String = "open"
    Const MinimumSuccess    As Long = 32
    ' Shall not have a value for opening a document.
    Const Parameters        As String = ""
    
    Dim Handle      As Long
    Dim Directory   As String
    Dim Instance    As Long
    Dim Success     As Boolean
    
    Handle = GetDesktopWindow
    Directory = Environ("Temp")

    Instance = ShellExecute(Handle, OperationOpen, File, Parameters, Directory, ShowCommand)
    ' If the function succeeds, it returns a value greater than MinimumSuccess.
    Success = (Instance > MinimumSuccess)
    
    OpenDocumentFile = Success

End Function

It opens a converted file in the TEMP folder.
You can easily change the folder name passed to variable Directory.
