Excel VBA Run-time error 450 when applying Formatting
I have a VB macro in Excel which applies some formatting to the worksheet.
On one PC, this line of code always gives

error 450: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

    Columns("AK:AK").Select
    Selection.Style = "Percent"

On other PCs, it works fine though. The only difference is that PC has 64-bit Office, whereas others have 32-bit. Is that code not valid for 64-bit?

Your current code is valid for 64 bit. Post your full codes. I assume you have few functions that is not valid for VBA 7.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/64-bit-visual-basic-for-applications-overview

Read this answer from stack overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5514745/5514747

Wild guess. Try: Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00%". At least, that's what my version of Excel gives when a register a macro.

could you also try:
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("AK:AK").Style = "Percent"
or indeed as Robert suggested
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("AK:AK").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
